# MacbookPro Safari 12.0 rgba opacity problem

Tags: css, safari

this is my first post here.

I have a problem with my rgba proprieties on MacbPro15"/Safari12

This is my code for the black transparent overlay :

```
.overlay{
background:rgba(0,0,0,.8);
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
bottom:0;
right:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
z-index:1;
overflow:hidden;}
```

On Chrome I can see the opacity but when it's safari the overlay it just black, I need to put my rgba opacity at 0.2-0.3, but if I do that, this will be too low on Chrome

Thanks you for your answer

Comment: check this https://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Comment: Thanks, I did lot of change, so when I delete overflow:hidden it's work, I don't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with **background-color**:rgba(0,0,0,.8)
and not only background.